# How to enable the staple feature when printing from Oracle EBS?

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

We would like to enable the staple feature when printing from Oracle EBS. Basically we want the printouts stapled when sent to a printer from Oracle EBS.

This is only for a specific concurrent program output that is sent to a specific printer.

Our EBS installation runs on Linux server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If only requests from this program go to the printer, then this can be done by assigning the printer to the concurrent program and creating a new pasta config file for the printer. See section **Defining Configuration Files for Specific Printers** in the document below.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/doc.122/e22953/T174296T174303.htm

If the business rules are more complex, then one might also need to create a second printer and a custom concurrent program. The two printers would be staple printer (with custom config) or no staple printer (standard config). The custom concurrent program would determine whether or not staples need to be added. The custom program would call the original program and assign the correct printer.

Finally, if this program falls under Order Management, it might be possible to use the setups there to get your desired outcome.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/oe/asnprnt.htm